# openGl - 143 errors from the includes

Tags: opengl

I'm working on windows XP with Visual C++ 2008 Express Eition.
Im trying to include:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

and getting alot of errors like:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h(1152) : error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h(1152) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h(1152) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAccum'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h(1152) : error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'
```

etc.

My question is: can i use those includes or do i need to get those libraries from somewhere at first?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons known to Microsoft only, the OpenGL headers provided with the various Windows SDKs require that you

```
#include <windows.h>
```

before.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to compile it as C++ instead of C, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using SDKs named 'v6.0a' with VC++2K8? Are you sure that's the latest OpenGL headers you have? You should be using latest Platform SDK and OpenGL headers whenever possible.