# Error while trying to use OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, visual-studio-2005

I have a very simple C code in which I am trying to use OpenGl.
When I include the following files

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I get the following error(and many more but they are similar):
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'

but when I include

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I get the following error
\mainfile.cpp(4) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glut.h': No such file or directory

any idea what is happening?

I am using XP, VS2005

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GLUT isn't part of OpenGL. You need to install it, which is what that error says.

Comment: Google it. I use Linux, so I don't use binary installers.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html. Just copy the header files into your OpenGL place.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968306/opengl-143-errors-from-the-includes) you do need `windows.h` first.

On my SDK (v7.0a) there is no `glut.h`, just `gl.h` and `glu.h`.

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl


04/26/2011  05:00 PM    <DIR>          .
04/26/2011  05:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/30/2009  08:27 PM            69,085 GL.h
09/30/2009  08:27 PM            18,284 GLU.h
               2 File(s)         87,369 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  191,961,296,896 bytes free
```

Looks to me like you have to install the other header file by hand, per instructions [here](http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/cs371/visualstudio/).