# Visual C++ 2010 error. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-c++-2010

I am trying to run a sample tutorial on Visual C++ 2010 but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Unable to start program C:\Users\SVS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\3DTrialOne\Debug\3DTrialOne.exe 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have created a new project and added the source code into the new one. I have created a new project from existing code too. It still has the same error. Should I change anything in the configuration settings?

I have tried to point the working path in the configuration settings to the debug folder (just shooting blindly), but it still has the same error.

EDIT 2: Someone had the same problem with Visual Studio and posted this, [Having trouble with MS Visual Studio 2010](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=269610)
in OpenGL.org. Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Is there a `3DTrialOne.exe` _in_ the `C:\Users\SVS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\3DTrialOne\Debug` directory?

Comment: There isn't a 3DTrialOne.exe in the debug directory/

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates you're trying to run an exe file which isn't on the machine.
(or at least not at the path specified)

Try compiling the project.
If there are build errors, post those.

If you're able to compile the project ok;
then there's a problem with where VS thinks the executable to launch is.
( Try looking under settings, output directory )

Comment: There are build errors! Almost all of them are 

`project\cgfacetree.h(21): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glut.h': No such file or directory` 

I did make sure to include GL folder both in the project directory and the solution explorer.

Comment: Two things: (1) Did you include the GL folder or the _parent_ to the GL folder? (You want the parent.) (2) Is glut.h in the GL directory? IF not, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374637/error-while-trying-to-use-opengl

Comment: Include as in the program? #include <GL/glut.h>? yes. In the Solution explorer? Yes, I added in a new filter GL and added glut.h to it. The folder is also in the project directory.

Comment: There is a difference between doing a #include<...> and a #include "...", if GL is a subfolder of the project directory, and you haven't explicitly listed the project folder in the list of include directories... use #include "GL/glut.h"

Answer (score 1):

For me, my antivirus software was conflicting with the process of creating the exe, so before I opened visual studio, I would disable my antivirus. Then I would create a new project because otherwise the exe for that project would already be removed by antivirus. But if your worrying about having to start a new project each time, you don't have to. But just do it for the projects that the issue has already arisen in. Make sure to disable your antivirus each time, and THEN open visual studio.

Sorry if I am of no help, but this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change "\" to "/", it solved my issue and I caught at while I looked toward the warning.