# OpenCV Errors - Accurate eye center tracking

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors

```
1>C:\opencv243\build\include\constants.h(15): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const float'
1>C:\opencv243\build\include\constants.h(26): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const float'
1>prog.cpp(16): warning C4068: unknown pragma
1>prog.cpp(44): warning C4068: unknown pragma
1>prog.cpp(48): error C3861: 'round': identifier not found
1>prog.cpp(49): error C3861: 'round': identifier not found
1>prog.cpp(54): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>prog.cpp(74): warning C4068: unknown pragma
1>prog.cpp(189): warning C4068: unknown pragma
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I want to run accurate eye center tracking programme but these are my errors... Please help me to fix this.. I havent got enough time for this project..

(if All of my code is necessary , i can send it)

****EDİT****
The last status of my project; it have build errors.. :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MNOpenCV, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>hkjn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl computeDynamicThreshold(class cv::Mat const &,double)" (?computeDynamicThreshold@@YANABVMat@cv@@N@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl findEyeCenter(class cv::Mat,class cv::Rect_<int>,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?findEyeCenter@@YA?AV?$Point_@H@cv@@VMat@2@V?$Rect_@H@2@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>hkjn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl matrixMagnitude(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?matrixMagnitude@@YA?AVMat@cv@@ABV12@0@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl findEyeCenter(class cv::Mat,class cv::Rect_<int>,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?findEyeCenter@@YA?AV?$Point_@H@cv@@VMat@2@V?$Rect_@H@2@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>hkjn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl inMat(class cv::Point_<int>,int,int)" (?inMat@@YA_NV?$Point_@H@cv@@HH@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl floodShouldPushPoint(class cv::Point_<int> const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?floodShouldPushPoint@@YA_NABV?$Point_@H@cv@@ABVMat@2@@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\AA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MNOpenCV\Debug\MNOpenCV.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add the include for the "double round (double x)" function?

```
#include <math.h>
```

If not, it might be an issue with your pragma instructions...

[C++ Round Function Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/)

Best regards!

Comment: thank you for your help. and ı have new error. Like this subjects:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590482/visual-c-2010-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Comment: @AydınAyaydın try to delete the sdf file that VS creates, right click the solution, select Clean and then, build it again. Hope it works!